# PL/SQL block in triggers getting set to null

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Not sure how much information I can provide because I'm still not exactly sure why it happens, but the PL/SQL block in my triggers in Oracle SQL developer keep getting set to null at random times. It's happened when I've: dropped rows, enabled the trigger, compiled the trigger, inserted rows (through ODAP.net), and updated rows.

I've tried my best to find an answer, but I can't find anything. Any ideas would be much, much appreciated.

Also, was not sure whether or not to post here or serverfault.

Trigger is a variation of this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER basic_ticket_trg

BEFORE INSERT ON basic_ticket

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

  <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>>
  BEGIN
    IF INSERTING AND :NEW.ID IS NULL THEN
      SELECT basic_ticket_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM SYS.DUAL;
    END IF;
  END COLUMN_SEQUENCES;

END;
```

The if statement is what keeps getting set to null, so it ends up looking like:

```
create or replace TRIGGER basic_ticket_trg

BEFORE INSERT ON basic_ticket

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

  <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>>
  BEGIN
    null;
  END COLUMN_SEQUENCES;

END;
```

Comment: What exactly are you seeing? What gets 'set to null'? Are you saying the trigger definition is changing - so if you look in `all_source`, or use `dbms_matadata` to get the definition, it has changed unexpectedly?

Comment: Can you add the trigger source code to your question please?

Comment: @AlexPoole updated the question

Comment: Did you create the table from SQL Developer's new table wizard, and its 'column sequences' pane? Which version of SQL Developer are you using?

Comment: @AlexPoole using version 4.1.3.20. The table I created through the gui, though the trigger itself comes from a script that we just modify and run every time we need a trigger to add an ID. (the script is the same thing as the trigger above with an enable trigger statement at the end)

Comment: Are you sure that script (or a variation of it) isn't just being run by someone? I am wondering if SQL Developer might be confused because it looks like one it might have created itself (though the table wizard, advanced, identity option) - that seems pretty unlikely though. Something running externally seems much more likely. One of the SQL Developer - er - developers visits sometimes so might have an idea if you've 100% ruled that out.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. I create the table, then the sequence, then the trigger. When the trigger compiles, it shows up in the "Column Sequence" pane of the table gui, but I do not manually add that in when I create the table itself.

Starting to think it might actually be a permissions issue with the user I was on when I created the triggers, because when created by other users, they don't have that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not entirely 100% sure why it was happening, but for those viewing, it was caused by updating the table the trigger would act on.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get rid of the label: "COLUMN_SEQUENCES", just delete it and every thing will be perfect, at least it worked for me, I think it's a bug that erases the code to NULL when you have to drop a column or change its name.